# How to transfer user data from a VM1 to a VM3 website?

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart, database, user

I am going to replace a VM1 website with a VM3 one. They have over 1500 users, so it would be very good to transfer them over to the newer site rather than making them all sign up again.

Is it a case of copying data over from the initial database to the newer one for the VM3 website? Or are the two databases incompatible with each other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to preserve your sanity, don't even try to perform migration manually.

I have used Daycounts VM Migrator https://www.daycounts.com/shop/virtuemart-3/virtuemart-2-migrator.htm for migrating five (5) VM1 shops to VM2 in Joomla 2.5, and I have only words of praise for that extension's quality, stability and scalability.

It's latest version now supports migrating to VM3 and Joommla 3 itself, and I Highly Recommend It to everyone in need of VM shop migration.

Comment: I will be needing to go from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5 as well as VM1 to VM3. Can this add on do a Joomla migration as well? I've got a test/clone site working so I'm going to test manual migration on there first.

Comment: VM Migrator DOES Joomla migration as well, and it does it very good. Worth every penny IMHO.

Comment: We bought the extension but its not installing from both directory or as a file. I've tried it with both the folder in the directory and the zip folder in the directory and as a file but errors just pop up. I've set all permissions ok and tried making folders manually in components and administration-components but still errors. I've opened a ticket with them, if it doesn't work I'll have to get a refund.